# Localstack block cors when use Commandeer dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cors, localstack

Commander 403 error：

[image]

I'm using the commandeer to run a local instance of aws, but some services I need, such as Dynamo, Cloudformation, SNS and SQS are off with error 403 in the commandeer. When I open the docker terminal, the following error message appears:

```
2021-08-18T17:12:11:INFO:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Blocked cors request from forbidden origin app://.
```

I'm running localstack inside a docker container, with the official localstack image in the latest version. The only settings I made to the container was to expose port 4566.

When I try to create some resource locally via code or via aws cli command everything works, but I can't use the commandeer on these resources.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, in the newest version of LocalStack it will throw a CORS issue for some of the services.  If you set EXTRA_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = app://. it will allow the app to work.  You can read more about this here -  https://docs.getcommandeer.com/docs/LocalStack/localstack-cors-issues  The very important part is it need to have the . at the end.  That caused an issue for a while before we figured it out.